# Python 2.7 error downloading Dropbox file by urllib.urlretrieve

Tags: android, python, dropbox, kivy, urllib

The code I used (don't mind the image, it's a test one):

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve('https%3A//dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95587456/Evenimente/1.jpg','/storage/emulated/0/Temp/1.jpg')
```

I tried to download an image by its public dropbox link, only for this error to pop up:

```
I/python  ( 3750):  Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python  ( 3750):    File "/home/cristi/Desktop/AplicatieMinister/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 102, in <module>
"/home/cristi/Desktop/AplicatieMinister/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 63, in IncarcaAfise
I/python  ( 3750):    File "/home/cristi/Desktop/AplicatieMinister/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 91, in urlretrieve
I/python  ( 3750):    File "/home/cristi/Desktop/AplicatieMinister/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 237, in retrieve
I/python  ( 3750):    File "/home/cristi/Desktop/AplicatieMinister/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 205, in open
I/python  ( 3750):    File "/home/cristi/Desktop/AplicatieMinister/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 461, in open_file
I/python  ( 3750):    File "/home/cristi/Desktop/AplicatieMinister/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 475, in open_local_file
I/python  ( 3750):  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95587456/Evenimente/1.jpg'
```

Running this code on Windows has no issues (it downloads the file), but on android (after compiling it as an APK by buildozer) it gives the previous error.

I tried adding ?dl=1 and ?dl=0 at the end of the link, and it ended up in the same error. Also, I tried urllib.quote on the link (and replacing the '$3A' with ':') and it still gave this error.

Is there anything I have overlooked regarding how urllib and urlretrieve work under android?

Also, if it helps, Kivy/buildozer were used in the development of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the stack trace, it appears that `urllib.urlretrieve` thinks your Dropbox URL is a local file path, as opposed to an Internet URL, and is attempting to open it as such. (I.e., it tries to use `open_local_file`.) That is supposed to be automatically determined based on the format of the URL, but this is apparently confused by your attempt to escape the ":", which should be unnecessary.

Your sample code actually fails the same way for me, just in the Python interpreter:

```
In [1]: import urllib

In [2]: urllib.urlretrieve('https%3A//dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95587456/Evenimente/1.jpg','./1.jpg')
...
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95587456/Evenimente/1.jpg'
```

That being the case, are you sure you've run the code you thought were you on the different platforms as you mentioned?

Just fixing the URL back to normal works for me:

```
In [1]: import urllib

In [2]: urllib.urlretrieve('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95587456/Evenimente/1.jpg','./1.jpg')
Out[2]: ('./1.jpg', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x10da6d878>)
```

(I also modified the second parameter to make it work on my computer, but that's unrelated.)

Comment: This fixed the issue; however, I ran into another problem on the same command but I'll make a new question for that (different error).